# Connecting Dots

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I want to connect a grid of dots using connectors. Right now, I am creating the connector separately from the dots. Is there a quicker way to recreate this effect in Illustrator?

The Grid
[image: Text]

The effect I am trying to achieve
[image: Text]

Separate connectors
[image: Text]

Answer (score 5):

What you need is the **Metaball** script created by http://shspage.com/

Simply go here: http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#metaball

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I propose we universally change the name of this effect to *meatball* – makes way more sense than **metaball** anyways. ;)

Comment: Funny @dom I've always referred to it as "meatball" `:)` It wasn't until your comment I that I looked more closely `:)` Meatball makes sense.. what the heck is a "metaball"? Can you be dyslexic regarding just one single word?

Answer (score 1):

Paste it to Photoshop and apply Filter > Noise > Median:

[image]

If it must be vector trace it.