# What is the easiest and most precise way to accomplish such a graphic in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

I was wondering how one would approach a graphic like this[image] in Illustrator. And when I talk about this graphic I am actually talking about the connection between the circles.

Comment: https://shanfan.github.io/Illustrator-Scripts-Archive/ See Metaball-Arc, Metaball

Comment: I've re-opened this, because I don't think it's quite the same question as the proposed duplicate, even though one answer to it does mention a script which could be used for this. I think it's worthwhile exploring other methods.

Comment: Also connected to this question with interesting answer from Scott: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152512/connecting-dots

Comment: Dunno.. still feel like it's a duplicate @BillyKerr `:)` I mean, run the script then refine. Not much more to it than that. Provided answers are nice, but they are *way* overthinking things. So, I added an answer showing how dead simple using the script is.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to get fairly accurate tangential curves to circles using some 45° rotated squares as guides, i.e. squares that are the same size as the radius of each circle, rotated around the circles' centres using the Rotate tool, and then drawing a path with the Pen tool, making sure that the bézier handles of the curve snap to the corners of the squares.

Example

[image]

Then you can copy and paste the path you made, and reflect it 180° and move it so that the ends snap to the centre of the circles

[image]

Then once you have your shapes, you could use the Shape Builder tool to make the pieces.

[image]

And finally you can use the Direct Selection tool to select all the anchors of one side, and freely move them.

[image]

Or even scale them

[image]

Here's a zoomed in shot showing the accuracy of the tangent, in outline view.

[image]

Comment: A curve is perfectly tangential with a circle if its endpoint handle is in parallel with a 90 degrees rotated radius.

Comment: @user287001 - yeah I know. That's why I suggested using a square as a guide to make sure the handle is at 90 degrees to the radius.

Answer (score 5):

One easy method to get symmetric bridges with no 3rd party plugins:

[image]

Draw a line between the centers of the circles.

Use the Width Tool to make the bridge have good looking width variation. You must insert width adjustment handles at both ends, in the midway between the circles and at about in the midpoints of the circle radiuses.

Learn from the User's Guide how to insert, move, adjust and remove the width handles. It's quite easy to insert too many of them accidentally.

Finally bring the circles to front and select the colors.

**Important:** It's useful to have from the start colored circles with no stroke because it's quite easy to adjust accidentally the width of the circle stroke when you make the bridge. I used no fill to make the handles well visible in my screenshots.

This method is based on eyeballing, it doesn't make automatically bridges which meet the circles tangentially. But the result is symmetric with no effort.

**Moving a bridged circle:**

If you want to move an already bridged circle, drag with the direct selection tool over the circle and move one of the nodes of the circle. Other nodes and the line end follow:

[image]

Unfortunately the places of the width handles are automatically adjusted proportionally, as you see in the image. The width handles which originally were in the midpoints of the circle radiuses are now outside the circles and make the look somehow bulged. They must be moved or deleted and new ones must be drawn inside the circles:

[image]

**Another no extra software (eyeballing) method** is to draw it with the pen. Click only to get a polygon and draw the handles later if you are not well familiar with the pen:

[image]

Drag the handles out of the corners with the anchor type tool and color the bridge:

[image]

It's not automatically symmetric nor tangential and moving a circle in practice forces you to redraw the bridge, but with a little practicing one draws a smooth looking bridge in half a minute.

**You may say:** "It must be symmetric and tangential with no eyeballing, I want perfect snaps.

In that case one working idea is to get a CAD extension plugin for Illustrator. I do not have such software, I show the idea in a simple CAD program (=TurboCAD dlx). It gives a possibility to draw an arc which is tangential with 3 already drawn curves:

[image]

There are numerous low cost and free 2D CAD programs with the same capability. Illustrator CAD plugins are not free.

The magenta dashed lines are automatic rectangular snapping guides which vanish soon. I have inserted a small circle on the connection line between the 2 bigger circles to have the 3rd item.

The result can be exported as SVG, PDF or EMF to be used in Illustrator. A CAD plugin would work directly in Illustrator.

If the circles happen to be  on the same horizontal or vertical line  tangential arcs or other curves can be drawn quite easily also without plugins. Older cases in GDSE show some methods. You have also got an answer which shows one way.

**But you may continue**: I'm not going to get plugins nor CAD programs. and the circles are already in good places, I'm not going to rotate them to make tangentials easy to draw"

The case is not hopeless, but you must apply some antique geometry ideas to get the right arcs. Close temporarily in the Layers panel every other objects except the 2 circles which need a bridge. See the next image:

[image]

Draw a circle (black stroke, no fill) which has radius = the wanted radius of the edge arcs of the forthcoming bridge. Duplicate. Place the new circles to touch the orange and brown circle at 9 o'clock and 3 o'clock nodes. If you have Smart Guides and Snap to Points ON you can drag the circles easily to the right places and see they snap. Only select a circle with the normal selection tool and move a node holding the Ctrl key - you have got temporarily the direct selection tool ON. With it the whole circle comes along and the moved node snaps.

Draw 2 vertical lines (=hold Shift) to the centers of the new circles:

[image]

The lines are needed to have good snapping in the next step. Draw 2 new circles from the centers of the original colored circles (=hold Shift+Alt, the circles are magenta) so that the radiuses are the original radiuses + plus the radius of the black circle:

[image]

Add new anchor points to the crossings of the magenta circles. Move the black circles to the new points:

[image]

Delete the magenta circles. Fill the space between the circles with the Shape Builder:

[image]

The new shape is your bridge. Colorize it as you like and delete the extras:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An easy method....

Draw your circles...

[image]

Select all the circles ...

Run the [**MetaBall Script**](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#metaball)... (which is a simple *javascript* file, *not* a plugin. And it's **free**)

[image]

Then simply delete what you don't want and alter any coloring and stacking order as necessary.

[image]

**Took me *maybe* 30 seconds.. drawing the circles took longer than creating the connectors.**

The script allows you to control the rate of the curves in the connectors....

[image]

It's not necessary to use the script on *all* the circles at once. You can do them 2, 3, 4 at a time if you'd prefer more varied curve rates between things. You simply need a *minimum of 2 circles* selected for the script to run.

There's no measuring, no curve refining, no width adjusting.. just simple steps thanks to the script. You can always delete a single connector shape, select two circles and run the script again to recreate the connector quickly if something changes.